# Is there a semantic equivalent of Swift "guard let" statement in C#?

Tags: c#, swift

In Swift there's a [guard let](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/) statement for optional binding:

```swift
var opt: Int? = 5
// var opt: Int? = nil

guard let nonOptional: Int = opt else { return }
```

This `guard let` statement allows us extract an `Int` value if it's there (in the following example it's `5`), and do not extract a `nil` value if optional equals `nil` (because if it equals `nil` – an app will crash).

I'd like to know what a semantic equivalent in C# is?

Comment: I don't like this type of questions. You're limiting yourself to answers from people that knows enough about both languages - I would suggest in the future try to describe the kind of semantic you're looking for in plain English, so that even people that doesn't know the source language can help you - but that's just me.

Comment: @ZoharPeled,  I've published a more descriptive text in my question (although there was a link about what "guard let" is).

Comment: I see. So basically it's a parameters validator. Nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not as of right now. There is a proposal open (since February 2017) on the C# GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/138).

C# way of doing would be something along the lines of

```cs
var optional = (int?) 5;

...

int nonOptional;
if (optional.HasValue)
    nonOptional = optional.Value;
else
    return;
```

As you can see, it's quite wordy, but that's because we are dealing with a [`Nullable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) value type not a reference type. For reference types it becomes much easier and conciser:

```cs
var optional = (string) null;

...

if (optional == null)
    return;

// We known from now on that 'optional' is not null
```

Answer (score 4):

As of C# 9, the answer is yes!

The following C# is the equivalent of the Swift code in the question:

```
int? optional = 5;
// int? optional = null;
if (optional is not int nonOptional)
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then something like this (I can’t check the code at the moment)

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    int? optional = 5;
    var nonOptional = ValueTypeHelper.IsNullable(optional) ? throw new Exception() : optional;
    Console.WriteLine(nonOptional);
}

public static class ValueTypeHelper
{
    public static bool IsNullable<T>(T t) { return false; }
    public static bool IsNullable<T>(T? t) where T : struct { return true; }
}
```

Comment: This will [not work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GETuZQ)

Comment: @STALER - It seems to me that `var nonOptional = optional == null ? throw new Exception() : optional;` is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the fix in the code and I'll remove my downvote

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in the latest C# supported by .NET 6:

In Swift:

```swift
guard let currentState = InputState.Inputting else { do something }
if let currentState = InputState.Inputting { do something}
```

In C#:

```cs
if (state is not InputState.Inputting currentState) do something;
if (state is InputState.Inputting currentState) do something;
```

or

```cs
if (state is not {} currentState) do something;
if (state is {} currentState) do something;
```

P.S.: Andy's answer is enough but he did only mention the equivalent of if-let.